# Associative Array SCSS/SASS

Tags: arrays, sass

I need to convert numbers into words, so:

- "1-3" -> "one-third"
- "3-3" -> "three-thirds"
- "2-5" -> "two-fifths"

The numbers are generated in a loop, which should output a bunch of different class names like `one-third` or `one-half`:

```
$number = 3;

@for $i from 1 through $number-1 {
    // some calculations to output those classes: ".one-third", ".two-thirds"

    // The following currently outputs class names like ".1-3" and ".2-3"
    .#{$i}-#{$number} {
        // CSS styles
    }
}
```

I think I need to use two different associative arrays, which in PHP (just as an example) might look like:

```
$1 = array( 
   "1"=>"one", 
   "2"=>"two", 
   "3"=>"three" 
);

$2 = array( 
   "1"=>"whole", 
   "2"=>"half", 
   "3"=>"third" 
);
```

Is it possible in **SASS**/**SCSS** to create associative arrays at all or is there any workaround?

Comment: The upcoming version of Sass - v3.3 - introduces maps, which can be used like associative arrays: https://github.com/nex3/sass/blob/master/doc-src/SASS_CHANGELOG.md#sassscript-maps

Answer (score 68, accepted):

In Sass < 3.3 you can use multidimensional lists:

```
$numbers: (3 "three") (4 "four");

@each $i in $numbers {
    .#{nth($i,2)}-#{nth($i,1)} {
        /* CSS styles */
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/8613363)

In Sass >= 3.3 we get maps:

```
$numbers: ("3": "three", "4": "four");

@each $number, $i in $numbers {
    .#{$i}-#{$number} {
        /* CSS styles */
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/8613379)

---

So in terms of fractions, you could just do something in this direction, so that you don't need multiple lists or maps:

```
$number: 6;
$name: (
    ("one"),
    ("two" "halv" "halves"),
    ("three" "third" "thirds"),
    ("four" "quarter" "quarters"),
    ("five" "fifth" "fifths"),
    ("six" "sixth" "sixsths")
);
```

and then whatever you want to do with your loops ... maybe even something like this =D

```
@for $i from 1 to $number {
  @for $j from 2 through $number {
    .#{ nth( nth( $name, $i ), 1 ) }-#{
      if( $i>1,
        nth( nth( $name, $j ), 3 ),
        nth( nth( $name, $j ), 2 )
      )} {
        /* CSS styles */
    }
  }
}
```

[DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/8613644)

(I wrote it this way so that you can notice in `@for`, that using `to` goes to `n - 1`)

Comment: Thank you, that works great. Didn't know about multidimensional lists until now. I wasn't sure why u used nth two times, but after testing it, i found out that you had to because the list obviously is multidimensional.

Answer (score 11):

in addition to answer by Martin, my example for using colors as variables, that also works with color-processing functions like `darken()`:

```
$blue: rgb(50, 57, 178);
$green: rgb(209, 229, 100);
$orange: rgb(255, 189, 29);
$purple: rgb(144, 19, 254);

$colors: (
        "blue": $blue,
        "green": $green,
        "orange": $orange,
        "purple": $purple
);

@each $name, $color in $colors {
  .tc-#{$name} { color: #{$color} !important; }
  .bgc-#{$name} { background-color: #{$color} !important; }
}
```