# run loop to seven times for days in a week in scss

Tags: css, sass

I have days variable:

```
$days: M T W T F S S;
```

and static css as :

```
.bp3-control.bp3-checkbox input ~ .bp3-control-indicator::before {
background-image: unset;
content: "M";
padding: 7px 13px;
}
```

I want to set content Monday to Sunday in different checkboxes sequentially.

expected output :

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344891/associative-array-scss-sass#21348291), maybe that'll help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$days: (1 "M") (2 "T") (3 "W") (4 "T") (5 "F") (6 "S") (7 "S");


@each $i in $days {
    .bp3-control.bp3-checkbox:nth-child(#{nth($i, 1)}) input ~ .bp3-control-indicator::before {
        content: "#{nth($i,2)}";
    }
}
```

Checkout https://jsfiddle.net/moorthyrweb/3L1x5tva/

Comment: only last one is coming

Comment: Which sass version?

Comment: Could you share me your expected css output?

Comment: added in question

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$list: M T W T F S S;

  @each $day in $list{
    .bp3-control.bp3-checkbox input ~ .bp3-control-indicator::before {
      background-image: unset;
      content: "#{$day}";
      padding: 7px 13px;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: only last one is coming

Comment: Take a look [Link](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/4e29d251d2b8cd246d7f0bfdea81f09d)

Comment: added expected output in question

Comment: you need to add html murkup manually. scss can generate only classes name. I think this will helpful for you [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/gjt9whep/2/) . Thanks